# How to modify and bind response to DTO

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson-databind

I am very new to spring boot development. 
Currently, I am using `@FeignClient` to call external API and I want to bind it to my DTO.

My `DTO` looks like

```
public class TestDTO {
    private UUID uuid;
    private String name;
}
```

My `@FeignClient`,

```
@FeignClient(name = "testClient", url = "http://extenalApi/getRules")
public interface DataClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    List<TestDTO> getRules();
}
```

It throws an error because external API response is a bit different

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "customRule": {
                "name": "SAMPLE 1",
                "id": "0AB58A47D3A64B56A6B74DA0E66935DD"
            }
        },
        {
            "customRule": {
                "name": "SAMPLE 2",
                "id": "0AE6C846EAF648D1926E665E63633A94"
            }
        }
  }
```

how can I parse this JSON and make it to

```
[ 
   {
      "name": "SAMPLE 2",
      "id": "0AE6C846EAF648D1926E665E63633A94"
   },
   { ...
   }
]
```

as my DTO demands.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have different structure of API reponse.

Create a new container to hold API response of rules api:

```java
public class RulesDTO {
    private List<DataDto> data;

    //getter setter

    class DataDto{
      TestDTO customRule;

      //getter setter
    }

}
```

change method to getRules:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    RulesDTO getRules();
```

Now parse it to List of TestDTO for your response:

```java
List<TestDTO> yourData =  data.stream().map(DataDto::getCustomRule).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note- It is not working code. Just to give you an idea.